# Inserting each array value as a seperate row in codeigniter from controller to model

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I am getting array values dynamically but I am not able add the array values as a separate row into the MySQL database in codeigniter.

The output from Ajax is A 1000 B 400

**Controller**

```
$myTableArray = json_decode($_POST['myTableArray'], true);

$appointment_id=$this->user_model->get_details();

$details=$this->user_model->patient_investigation_details($myTableArray,$appointment_id);
```

**Model**

```
function get_details()
{
  $this->db->trans_start();
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * from `appointment_details` ORDER BY `appointment_id` DESC");
  $this->db->trans_complete();
  if($query->num_rows()>=1)
    return $query->result()[0]->appointment_id;
}

function patient_investigation_details($myTableArray,$appointment_id)
{
  $query_string="INSERT into `patient_investigation_details`(`investigation_name`,`price`,`appointment_id`) VALUES";
  foreach ($myTableArray as $row)
  {
    $query_string.="('".$row['1']."','". $row['2']."','".$appointment_id."')";
  }
  $this->db->trans_start();
  $query = $this->db->query($query_string);
  $this->db->trans_complete();

  if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE){
   return null;
  }
  else{
   return TRUE;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Could you please verify the code below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to create an array for insertion and then insert those in batch. Which will iterate the foreach loop and create the insert array

Also for getting `appointment_id` there is no need to pull *(all) from table. Just get the appointment_id  from it by apply limit 1 to get top most row

```
    function get_details()
    {
        $this->db->trans_start();
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT appointment_id from `appointment_details` ORDER BY `appointment_id` DESC limit 1");
        $this->db->trans_complete();
        if($query->num_rows()>=1)
            return $this->db->get()->row()->appointment_id;
    }

    function patient_investigation_details($myTableArray,$appointment_id)
    {
     foreach ( $myTableArray as $row){
            $data[] = array(
                    'investigation_name' => $row['1'],
                    'price'=> $row['2'],
                    'appointment_id'=>$appointment_id
            );
        }
    $this->db->insert_batch('patient_investigation_details', $data);
    }
```

Comment: thankyou @Nishant Nair i tried this.....but when i var_dump my appointment id i am not able to get the id and its  not being inserted into db

Comment: try with you code of `get_details()` and then try for inserting with my code

Comment: yeah i will try now

Comment: i got the output@nishant nair....thankyou so much.... Sorry i didnt load the model  $this->load->model('user_model'); so i didnt get the output...